# Got an error while parsing XML with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Hello I'm trying to Parse an Xml datei from an Api, ich habe just wrote this code :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://iliass-jobs.personio.de/xml?language=de", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;

parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
```

[I get this Error on printing the doc value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlOSH.png)

Comment: By "error", do you mean the `[Depreciation] ...`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method parseFromString  will expect a string value, but your response is in xml format.

So convert it to string by using serializeToString method like,

```
var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
```

then use the xmlString as param in parseFromString().

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. The actual HTTP message contains lexical XML. Asking for the `responseXML` property causes that lexical XML to be parsed into a DOM tree. The problem with the OP's code is that it is parsing the XML twice. You've already got an unnecessary parse step; solving it by adding an unnecessary serialization step to reverse the effect of the parse step is, let's say, not the most elegant of solutions. Either use the `responseText` and parse it by calling a DOMParser, or just use the `responseXML` directly.